# React-Slick Slider Giving Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function"

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm only having this problem when using the package 'react-slick'. I didn't have this problem the night before but when spinning up my dev server today it presents me with this error.[image]

I've already tried reinstalling my node_modules to no avail. When I remove the  component the error goes away. I've used this package all over my application and everything just broke on the same day! Other parts of the application are working fine however.

Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppConsumer } from '../../../Context';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import Slide from './Slide';

const SliderContainer = styled.div `
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
`;

const StudioContainer = () => <AppConsumer>{context => <StudioComponent context={context} />}</AppConsumer>

class StudioComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            slideIndex: 0
        }
    }

    // Triggers the slidershow to go a direction
    next = () => this.slider.slickNext();
    prev = () => this.slider.slickPrev();

    render(props) {
        const { slideIndex } = this.state;
        const { studioVids, questions } = this.props.context.state;
        const { addVideo, deleteVid } = this.props.context;

        // Settings for the Slider
        const settings = {
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            arrows: false,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            swipe: false,
            beforeChange: (current, next) => this.setState({ slideIndex: next })
        };

        return(
            <SliderContainer>

                 <Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)}  {...settings}>
                    {
                        questions.map((question, i) => (
                            <Slide key={`VideoSlide_${i}`} 
                            id={i} 
                            questionLength={questions.length} 
                            question={question} 
                            next={() => this.next()} 
                            prev={() => this.prev()} 
                            current={slideIndex}
                            addVid={addVideo}
                            deleteVid={deleteVid}
                            studioVids={studioVids}
                            />
                        ))
                    }     
                </Slider>

            </SliderContainer>
        );
    }
}

const Studio = () => StudioContainer(StudioComponent);

export default Studio;
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove 'node_module' directory and then reInstall them? I have some other problem which b solved by removing directory and reinstalling

Comment: Yes I have and it sadly did nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the HOC correctly. StudioContainer in your case has mixed syntax of an HOC and functional component. Making StudioContainer an HOC that takes a Component and return as Functional component would work.

```
const StudioContainer = (StudioComponent) => () => <AppConsumer>{context => <StudioComponent context={context} />}</AppConsumer>

class StudioComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            slideIndex: 0
        }
    }

    render(props) {
        const { slideIndex } = this.state;

        // Settings for the Slider
        const settings = {
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            arrows: false,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            swipe: false,
            beforeChange: (current, next) => this.setState({ slideIndex: next })
        };

        return(
            <div>
                 <Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)}  {...settings}>
                    <div><p>1</p></div>
                    <div><p>2</p></div>
                </Slider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Studio = StudioContainer(StudioComponent);

export default Studio;
```

or you could simply use it like

```
const StudioContainer = () => 
    <AppConsumer>
        {context => <StudioComponent context={context} />}
     </AppConsumer>


const Studio = () => <StudioContainer />;
```

Comment: Are you sure thats the correct syntax? I use that syntax everywhere and its fine. Your code however returned an error
"Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Comment: Which method did you use. The first or the second

Comment: The first I can't use the second I am using the context API in my lifecycle events. I just cut them out since they are unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Can you make sure you are rendering Studio component correctly like `<Studio />`

Comment: Yes everything in the view renders correctly but when I add the <Slider /> even without the settings or ref it returns the same error. When removed everything works just fine.

Comment: Can you show your context, I just tried the above example in a codesandbox and it works. Also what is your version of react-slick

Comment: Alright I've done it but again I get the same error even without ANY context API connection on the page.....

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just reverted to version (0.21.0).
I still don't know why the new version broke.

Answer (score 0):

You could experience that problem whe using why-you-update npm with react-slick (more info: https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update/issues/48 )